# Update table using post in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I develop my app using codeigniter. I have a table that generated from mysql table. this is the view :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.  </th>
        <th>No Request</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Waktu Kirim Request</th>
        <th>Keluhan</th>                                            
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Estimasi Penyelesaian</th>                                            
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($data_request as $data) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $no++ . ". "; ?> </td>
        <td class="sorting1" id='no_request'><?php echo $data['kode_kantor'] . '/' . $data['kode_departement'] . '/' . date('m', strtotime($data['bulan'])) . '/' . $data['id_request']; ?> </td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo "$nama"; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo date("d-m-Y, H:i ", strtotime($data['waktu_mulai'])); ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $data['keluhan']; ?></td>                                            
        <td class="center"><a href="#" onclick="ubahStatus();"><span class="label label-important"><?php echo $data['status_request']; ?> </span></a></td> 
        <td class="center"><?php echo date("d-m-Y, H:i ", strtotime($data['waktu_tutup_request'])); ?></td>                                            
        <td  class="center">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
                <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-success" >
                <i class="halflings-icon white print" id="print"></i>
            </a>         
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h2>Confirm</h2>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p id="id_preview"></p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" id="btn-footer" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="executeStatus();">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>   
</div>
```

The table like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/xammqf0u/5/embedded/result/

Now, to print a pdf, In [No.Request] field, there are string like this

```
TMS/IT/01/002,
```

I just want grab '002', because my funtion like this :

```
function generate_pdf($id){
    //some code here
}
```

which is the 002 woul be a parameter. How can I grab the field in table on the modal ?

Answer (score 1):

you could get the value and [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it, as:

```
var idStr = $this.attr("req_id");
var id = idStr.split("/").pop();
alert(id); //gives 002  send it to your post
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xammqf0u/7/)

Answer (score 0):

edit your html cell like this :

```
<td class="sorting1" id='no_request' data-id="<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>"><?php echo $data['kode_kantor'] . '/' . $data['kode_departement'] . '/' . date('m', strtotime($data['bulan'])) . '/' . $data['id_request']; ?> </td>
```

And in your javascript, add a POST parameter like this :

```
[...]
data: { 'id': $(this).data().id },
[...]
```

Comment: can u give me more specific example in javascript code above ?

Comment: post your javascript AJAX call, and I could show you how to post this specific data

Comment: I just forked your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zd4andh0/ added `data-id="001"` on your Print buttons (make it dynamic with $data['id_request'] of course). And added `var id = $this.data().id; console.log(id);` in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example by setting id´s to your table column and to your button:

```
<input type="button" id="button[<idFromDatabasePlacedHere>]" value="..." />
```

Also give the same id to your column:

```
<td id="column[<idFromDatabasePlacedHere>]">...</td>
```

And then you could read id in Javascript like this:

```
$("input[id^='button']").click(
function(sender)
{
var arSplit = $("#column" + $(this).attr("id").substring(6, $(this).attr("id").length - 1).attr("id").split("/");
// arSplit[3] is e. g. 002 is your key to work on
// not sure, if 6 is the character after column[ (not tested)
});
```